# Ordenar objecto dentro de objeto por valor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tengo dudas sobre cuál sería la mejor forma para ordenar estos ID's por fecha:

```
{
  "19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG": {
    "S": "15-12-2018"
  },
  "1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW": {
    "S": "31-12-2018"
  },
  "1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww": {
    "S": "31-12-2018"
  },
  "3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6": {
    "S": "31-12-2018"
  },
  "4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J": {
    "S": "5-4-2019"
  },
  "4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g": {
    "S": "15-12-2018"
  },
  "6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq": {
    "S": "31-12-2018"
  }
}
```

Tengo dudas sobre hacerlo concatenando un forEach con un for in. El caso es que me gustaría hacerlo de la forma más óptima posible para no perder rendimiento, quizás utilizando ES6

Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que has puesto ahí es un objeto, no un array, por tanto la única forma de recorrer todas las propiedades es con un `for ... in` o usando Object.keys(obj) para luego hacer un forEach sobre las claves.

Answer (score 1):

Cómo has pedido ES6, hay muchos acercamientos para lograr lo que pides. En este ejemplo te muestro alguno de ellos:

```js
const objetoIds = {
  '19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG': {
    S: '15-12-2018'
  },
  '1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW': {
    S: '31-12-2018'
  },
  '1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww': {
    S: '31-12-2018'
  },
  '3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6': {
    S: '31-12-2018'
  },
  '4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J': {
    S: '5-4-2019'
  },
  '4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g': {
    S: '15-12-2018'
  },
  '6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq': {
    S: '31-12-2018'
  }
};

// Función para convertir las fechas a formato UTC,
// para poder realizar la comparación de las mismas.
// Es una reutilización de lo propuesto por 'ramirozap'
const convertirFecha = strFecha => {
  const fecha = strFecha.split('-');
  return Date.UTC(fecha[2], parseInt(fecha[1]) - 1, fecha[0]);
};

// PASO 1
const _map = new Map();
Object.keys(objetoIds).map(_ => {
  _map.set(_, objetoIds[_]['S']);
});

// PASO 2
_map[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  yield* [...this.entries()].sort(
    ([, a], [, b]) => convertirFecha(a) - convertirFecha(b)
  );
};

// Paso 3a
const mapAsc = [..._map].map(([id, S]) => ({ id, S }));
console.log(mapAsc);

// PASO 3b
const _mapAsc = [..._map].reduce(
  (acc, [id, S]) => Object.assign(acc, { [id]: { S } }), {}
);
console.log(_mapAsc);
```

---

#### PASO #1:

Con el uso de [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map), primero se convierten cada uno de los objetos en valores tipo *hash*, obteniendo el formato `clave => valor`. En tu caso específico, el resultado queda de esta forma:

```
Map {
  '19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG' => '15-12-2018',
  '1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW' => '31-12-2018',
  '1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww' => '31-12-2018',
  '3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6' => '31-12-2018',
  '4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J' => '5-4-2019',
  '4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g' => '15-12-2018',
  '6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq' => '31-12-2018'
}
```

#### PASO #2:

Seguidamente se utilizan [`generadores`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Generador) tomando y cambiando [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Symbol/iterator) de [`Map.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) para obtener un resultado adaptado ordenando los elementos por fecha para devolverlos en forma de arreglo. El resultado de este paso queda así:

```
console.log([..._map_]);

[
  [ '19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG', '15-12-2018' ],
  [ '4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g', '15-12-2018' ],
  [ '1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW', '31-12-2018' ],
  [ '1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww', '31-12-2018' ],
  [ '3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6', '31-12-2018' ],
  [ '6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq', '31-12-2018' ],
  [ '4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J', '5-4-2019' ]
]
```

Es en este momento donde se pueden sacar, por ejemplo, 2 tipos de resultados:

#### PASO #3a: Arreglo de Objetos.

```
[
  { id: '19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG', S: '15-12-2018' },
  { id: '4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g', S: '15-12-2018' },
  { id: '1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW', S: '31-12-2018' },
  { id: '1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww', S: '31-12-2018' },
  { id: '3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6', S: '31-12-2018' },
  { id: '6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq', S: '31-12-2018' },
  { id: '4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J', S: '5-4-2019' }
]
```

#### PASO #3b: Formato de objetos, cómo fue colocado originalmente.

```
{
  '19huH6KOy0EYau0e0Oc6CG': { S: '15-12-2018' },
  '4gnGMMruak2qU0yQqy884g': { S: '15-12-2018' },
  '1Fr3I1pE6IcSEy4s0o0UwW': { S: '31-12-2018' },
  '1UIrWAsEP6YUyQEiy4WAww': { S: '31-12-2018' },
  '3extCHS2cg02YCY6GMEkG6': { S: '31-12-2018' },
  '6lk1HPWKNaY0mWkU0Io6iq': { S: '31-12-2018' },
  '4eQUYsAKvDYYT7113b3E6J': { S: '5-4-2019' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Primero y principal:** para ordenar los `id`s vas a tener que convertir el objeto en un array.

Para eso se puede usar `Object.keys()`.

Luego hay que ordenar los resultados usando `.sort()` sobre el array resultante de aplicar `Object.keys()`, 
si solo te interesa el orden de los `id`s ya te puedes detener aquí, 
si te interesa seguir teniendo la fecha lo que se puede hacer es usar un `.map()` sobre el resultado del sort para generar un array de objetos a partir del orden.

```js
const ids = {
  segundo: {
    S: "15-12-2018"
  },
  cuarto: {
    S: "31-12-2018"
  },
  quinto: {
    S: "5-4-2019"
  },
  tercero: {
    S: "23-12-2018"
  },
  primero: {
    S: "16-8-2018"
  }
};

function convertirFecha(strFecha) {
  const fecha = strFecha.split("-");
  return Date.UTC(fecha[2], parseInt(fecha[1]) - 1, fecha[0]);
}

const idsOrdenados = Object.keys(ids)
  .sort((idSiguiente, idActual) => {
    return (
      convertirFecha(ids[idSiguiente]["S"]) - convertirFecha(ids[idActual]["S"])
    );
  })
  .map(id => ({ id: id, S: ids[id]["S"] }));
  
console.log(idsOrdenados);
```